# Extracting information from an outlook contact or a distribution list saved as an *.msg file

Tags: c#, outlook, aspose, outlook-redemption, msg

I am trying to solve a problem where I have some contact information given as Outlook's ***.msg** files. I want to parse these files using a script to extract the contact emails and names. I tried couple of solutions:

- I tried using **Aspose's** email library but could not get to the contact details.
- If I open the **.msg** file with Outlook and save the file as a **.txt** file, the resulting file is a simple text file with the contact information listed and this file I can parse with the IO libraries and extract the information out. However I over hundred of these .msg files. I am using .NET and can't figure out how to implement the "*Save As*" text which I was able to do manually.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Thanks

Suresh

Answer (score 1):

Using Apose.Email API, we can extract the contact email information. You may try this on your end.I tired this and was able to extract those information

```
        MapiMessage message = MapiMessage.FromFile(msgPath);
        MapiPropertyCollection properties = message.NamedProperties;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<long, MapiProperty> prop in properties)
        {
            if (((prop.Value).Descriptor).CanonicalName != null)
            {
                if (((prop.Value).Descriptor).CanonicalName == "PidLidEmail1DisplayName")
                {
                    string email1displayName = prop.Value.ToString();                     
                }
                if (((prop.Value).Descriptor).CanonicalName == "PidLidEmail1EmailAddress")
                {
                    string email1Address = prop.Value.ToString();
                }
                if (((prop.Value).Descriptor).CanonicalName == "PidLidInstantMessagingAddress")
                {
                    string ADD = prop.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
session.Logon();
RDOFolder folder = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
Console.WriteLine("Extracting contacts...");

foreach (RDOFolder subFolder in folder.Folders)
{
    if (subFolder.Name == "CAS_Notifications")
    {
        foreach (var rdoItem in subFolder.Items)
        {
            RDOContactItem contactItem = rdoItem as RDOContactItem;
            RDODistListItem distList = rdoItem as RDODistListItem;
            if (distList != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Distribution List");
                foreach (RDOAddressEntry rdoAddressEntry in distList.OneOffMembers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}; Email: {1}", rdoAddressEntry.Name, rdoAddressEntry.SMTPAddress);
                }
            }
            else if (contactItem != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}; Email: {1}", contactItem.FullName, contactItem.Email1Address);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are very sorry for getting to you on this a little late.

What actual issue are you facing while using Aspose API? The API provides the capability to read Outlook Contact .MSG files as well as Distribution lists without the need of having MS Outlook installed. 
Please have a look at the following documentation articles:

- Working with [Outlook Contacts](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/emailnet/Creating%2C+Saving+and+Reading+Outlook+Contacts)

If you still face issue while retrieving the desired information with the latest version of the API, you can post your query along with sample MSG files to [Aspose.Email forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.email-product-family/188/showforum.aspx). We will investigate these at our end and assist you further.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), something like the following should work for reading contacts or distribution lists saved as msg files:

```
Redemption.RDOSession session = new Redemption.RDOSession();
Redemption.RDOMail msg = session.GetMessageFromMsgFile(@"c:\temp\TestContact.msg");
//is it really a contact? Could be a regular message or an RDODistListItem (all derived from RDOMail)
Redemption.RDOContactItem contact = msg as Redemption.RDOContactItem; 
if (contact != null)
{
  MessageBox.Show(contact.FirstName);
}
else 
{
   Redemption.RDODistListItem dl= msg as Redemption.RDODistListItem; 
   if (dl != null)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(dl.FileAs);
    }
}
```